# separating unique values in an algorithm

Tags: java

I am decomposing a series of 90,000+ strings into a discrete list of the individual, non-duplicated pairs of words that are included in the strings with the rxcui id values associated with each string.  I have developed a method which tries to accomplish this, but it is producing a lot of redundancy.  Analysis of the data shows there are about 12,000 unique words in the 90,000+ source strings, after I clean and format the contents of the strings.

How can I change the code below so that it avoids creating the redundant rows in the destination 2D ArrayList (shown below the code)?

```
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getAllWords(String[] tempsArray){//int count = tempsArray.length;
        int fieldslenlessthan2 = 0;//ArrayList<String> outputarr = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoDimArrayList= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        int idx = 0;
        for (String s : tempsArray) {
            String[] fields = s.split("\t");//System.out.println(" --- fields.length is: "+fields.length);
            if(fields.length>1){
                ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
                System.out.println("fields[0] is: "+fields[0]);
                String cleanedTerms = cleanTerms(fields[1]);
                String[] words = cleanedTerms.split(" ");
                for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++){
                    String word=words[j].trim();
                    word = word.toLowerCase();
                    if(isValidWord(word)){//outputarr.add(word);
                        System.out.println("words["+j+"] is: "+word);
                        row.add(word_id);//WORD_ID NEEDS TO BE CREATED BY SOME METHOD.
                        row.add(fields[0]);
                        row.add(word);
                        twoDimArrayList.add(row);
                        idx += 1;
                    }
                }
            }else{fieldslenlessthan2 += 1;}
        }
        System.out.println("........... fieldslenlessthan2 is: "+fieldslenlessthan2);
        return twoDimArrayList;
    }
```

The output of the above method currently looks like the following, with many rxcui values for some name values, and with many name values for some rxcui:

[image]

[image]

**How do I change the code above so that the output is a list of unique pairs of name/rxcui values, summarizing all relevant data from the current output while removing only the redundancies?**

Comment: You could use a UUID I guess.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html The static `randomUUID()` method generates them.

Comment: Can you use a `HashMap` this will automatically handle duplicates for you. You can also assign an id by incrementing or using the Strings `hashcode()`

Comment: @CodeMed I have provided a solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of the unique word ID? Is the word itself not unique enough since you are not keeping duplicates?

A very basic way would be to keep a counter going as you are checking new words. For each word that doesn't already exist you could increase the counter and use the new value as the unique id.

Lastly, might I suggest you use a HashMap instead. It would allow you to both insert and retrieve words in O(1) time. I am not entirely sure what you are going for, but I think the HashMap might give you more range.

**Edit2:**
It would be something a little more along these lines. This should help you out.

```
public static Set<DataPair> getAllWords(String[] tempsArray) {
    Set<DataPair> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (String row : tempsArray) {
        // PARSE YOUR STRING DATA
        // the way you were doing it seemed fine but something like this
        String[] rowArray = row.split(" ");
        String word = row[1];
        int id = Integer.parseInt(row[0]);
        DataPair pair = new DataPair(word, id);
        set.add(pair);
    }
    return set;
} 

class DataPair {
    private String word;
    private int id;

    public DataPair(String word, int id) {
        this.word = word;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof DataPair) {
            return ((DataPair) o).word.equals(word) && ((DataPair) o).id == id;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: From what it appears you should take a look at Brian Vanover's reposne, it is the direction I was thinking as well. You'll want to use a HashSet or HashMap most likely as these will both allow you to easily check for or handle duplicates.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you want the pair to be unique then? Because each ID could be linked to each word and each word could be linked to each ID? So you just want one of each pair to exist? I'll edit my post to include something that should help with this.

Comment: I updated it to match your code a little more closely. I might have parsed the string array wrong, I am not entirely sure what your input data looks like.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a Collection of all words, use a `HashSet` Sets are primarily used for contains logic. If you need to associate a value with your string use a `HashMap`

```
public HashSet<String> getUniqueWords(String[] stringArray) {
  HashSet<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>();
  for (String str : stringArray) {
    uniqueWords.add(str);
  }
  return uniqueWords;
}
```

This will give you a collection of all the unique Strings in your array. If you need an ID use a `HashMap`

```
String[] strList; // your String array
int idCounter = 0;
HashMap<String, Integer> stringIDMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String str : strList) {
  if (!stringIDMap.contains(str)) {
    stringIDMap.put(str, new Integer(idCounter));
    idCounter++;
  }
}
```

This will provide you a HashMap with unique String keys and unique Integer values. To get an id for a String you do this:
    stringIDMap.get("myString"); // returns the Integer ID associated with the String "myString"

**UPDATE**
Based on the question update from the OP. I recommend creating an object that holds the String value and the rxcui. You can then place these in a `Set` or `HashMap` using a similar implementation to the one provided above.

```
public MyObject(String str, int rxcui); // The constructor for your new object
MyObject mo1 = new MyObject("hello", 5);
```

Either

```
mySet.add(myObject);
```

will work or

```
myMap.put(mo1.getStr, mo1.getRxcui);
```

Comment: @CodeMed If there are many words with many different rxcui, you need a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` The key is the id and the value is an ArrayList containing all of the chemicals names associated with that id

Comment: @CodeMed create 2 HashMaps. One of type `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>` and one of type `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` That way you could get all rxcui associated with a certain name and all names associated with a certain rxcui by making different `get()` calls to your respective Maps